# /bin/ls -al --full-time does not recognize full-time in MacOS

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew

I have 128,000 image file I recovered from a hard-drive failure. The software I used treated duplicates and deleted files the same way. ie it restored everything. As a result I have up to five duplicates of every image file. And of course they are not sequential.

I want to be able to compare the exact file size and the exact creation date, so that I can create an un-dupe script.
This should be simple, but

```
ls -al --full-time gives me the exact time, but not size in bytes
/bin/ls -al gives me the size in bytes, but not the exact creation date.
```

I'm using the brew replacement, bash shell, on my imac.

Is there a way I can use either brew or native bash, to get both values?

As always, any help would be appreciated

Comment: (1) `\bin\ls` looks weird. Do you mean `/bin/ls`? (2) I don't know macOS at all. Can you use `jdupes` or `fdupes`? (3) If not (or if these tools are not good for you), can you use `stat`? [Parsing `ls` is hardly ever a good method](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: lol... too much time working in a windows environment. yes, it should be /bin/ls. Stat could work. I'll give it a try and let you know. I was fixated on using ls for some reason.

Comment: stat works well. Thanks for the tip.